# How to convert div tags to a table?

Tags: web-scraping, html-table

I want to extract the table from this website https://www.rankingthebrands.com/The-Brand-Rankings.aspx?rankingID=37&year=214
Checking the source of that website, I noticed that somehow the table tag is missing. I assume that this table is a summary of multiple div classes. Is there any easy approach to convert this table to excel/csv? I badly have coding skills/experience...
Appreciate any help

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Python/R, does not matter, as long as there is a working method.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few way to do that. One of which (in python) is (pretty self-explanatory, I believe):

```
import lxml.html as lh
import csv
import requests

url = 'https://www.rankingthebrands.com/The-Brand-Rankings.aspx?rankingID=37&year=214'
req = requests.get(url)

doc = lh.fromstring(req.text)
headers = ['Position', 'Name', 'Brand Value', 'Last']

with open('brands.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
    #note the 'a' in there - for 'append`
    file = csv.writer(fp)    
    file.writerow(headers)    
    
    #with the headers out of the way, the heavier xpath lifting begins:
    for row in doc.xpath('//div[@class="top100row"]'):
        pos = row.xpath('./div[@class="pos"]//text()')[0]
        name = row.xpath('.//div[@class="name"]//text()')[0]
        brand_val = row.xpath('.//div[@class="weighted"]//text()')[0]
        last = row.xpath('.//div[@class="lastyear"]//text()')[0]
        file.writerow([pos,name,brand_val,last])
```

The resulting file should be at least close to what you're looking for.